# How to Debug Phonegap Using the PhoneGap Developer App

Tags: cordova

Phonegap just came out with a way to instantly see your changes to your phonegap app using a local server by using this command:

```
phonegap serve
```

And then by downloading the PhoneGap Developer App. The instructions are here: http://app.phonegap.com/

But I'm used to being able to go to about:inspect in Chrome to use remote debugging (http://www.adamwadeharris.com/remote-debugging-in-phonegap-with-chrome-devtools/), but when I go to this page while the Phonegep Developer App is running, nothing shows up underneath the name of my phone. Is there a way to do this with the PhoneGap Developer App?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not supported. You will need to use something like Weinre instead.

Comment: That's too bad. I was really excited when I first saw this new app.

Comment: is going to be supporter or not?

Answer (score 3):

In order to remote debug on Android with Chrome, while running in Phonegap Developer App, you should use an apk that was built in debug mode.

You can clone the app [repo](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer) and build it yourself. You can also [download](http://msdevs.blogspot.co.il/2014/12/how-to-enable-chrome-for-android-remote.html) the debug mode apk from my blog.

Comment: Awesome! Is that a new feature?

Comment: How to debug after following the steps?

Answer (score 1):

AppGyver's [Steroids tooling](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids) provides a similar companion app to the PhoneGap Developer App, as well as access to the Chrome Inspector.

You can [run Steroids in your Cordova project](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/cli/usage-with-cordova/) directly without modifying any files.

(Disclaimer: I'm a programmer for AppGyver.)

Comment: Pretty cool! LiveReload option works with real connected devices also? or only for emulators?