# Debugging PhoneGap apps using WebView/GapDebug

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, debugging, webview

I'm working on my first phonegap app. Before going deep into the development, I really wanted to create a debugging environment. Here is what I got so far by researching on the web and trying those whole day.

The community is suggesting many tools, But I finally picked up **Chrome WebView and GapDebug**. Now I'm able to connect to the system using **USB Debugging**

I'm connecting the local server from my android device using the **PhoneGap Developer App** and it works fine. But my problem is, when I check the **chrome://inspect** it does listed the device. But no app is listed for the debugging.

Here is the screenshot from chrome.
[image]

Here no app is displayed while an app is running.

Here is the screenshot of GapDebug
[image]

And the PhoneGap server

[image]

I'm connecting the app using **192.168.137.1:3000**
I've added this in chrome **Port forwarding settings** and **GapDebug proxy setting** But no luck.

As per the documentation of GapDebug, I have set the following in my `config.xml`

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
 <application android:debuggable="true" />
</gap:config-file>
```

And added the `android:debuggable="true"` to the `<application>` element in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Can anyone suggest me how can I get the debugging tools working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't debug the phonegap developer app because it's a signed app downloaded from google play. You have to run your app on the device

try with this command, it should run your app

```
phonegap run android --device
```

or this one

```
phonegap cordova run android --device
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201289/how-to-debug-phonegap-using-the-phonegap-developer-app#answer-27583476). Can you please tell by editing which branch I can create debuggable build. There are 4 branches in the git of `developer-app`. 1)dev 2)integration-test 3)pgb-integration 4)push. I think I've to make modification in `pgb-integration`. Please confirm.

Comment: What I told you is not use the phonegap developer app, but compile your own app (not compile the phonegap developer app from the source). Phonegap developer app is a tool to preview your app, but in some moment you will have to build and test your real app, so do it now.